# open cv and c++ compile release without need library for run

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, codeblocks

first i have simple code with c++ and `opencv`

its no matter what is the code

now in windows i used visual studio and i add  the open cv library to visual stuio and compile it and its work but when i send it to another pc its need open cv library its hard to send all library so i find the program need some files like

> opencv_highgui2410.dll
>   ..... .dll
>   opencv_objdetect2410.dll

that's make my program run without the library

now i turned to ubuntu linux after i compile with codeblocks
this photo will show you how i linker the library

[image]

and

[image]

and i build the program and run it its work now when i sent the program to another pc its give an error some files not found like

`error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4`
i copy this file `libopencv_core.so.2.4` and add it beside the program still same error seems not like windows

any solution made me compile opencv program and run program without need full library just some of its file

or any idea to add files (libs) that's project needed to run beside program just like windows

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply install opencv using `apt get`?

Comment: @Frank  i uploaded my program in a host this the problem program give me
`error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4`

Comment: What I'm getting at is that distributing dependencies as binaries, while feasible, is something you really want to avoid if you can, especially for libraries that can be installed through the package manager.

Comment: now :/ the solution i need to run the program in linux host

Comment: my question remains, why not just run `apt-get install opencv` on the host?

Comment: @Frank can i do that's in cpanel ?

Comment: You can do that via ssh, if you got ssh access to that server (as you speak of cpanel, i suppose you are trying to run this script on a server managed by someone else)

Comment: @Frank no its my cpanel let me try that's

Comment: @Frank any tutorail about how to use ssh and install opencv ?

Comment: try below command for 'error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4' error
"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_libs"

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.
But from the comments, i fear you have very little linux experience, I hope this will help, anyway:

https://s1meonov.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/opencv-static-linking-gnulinux-gcc/

(first, be sure to understand what shared and static libraries, how they work and how they impact on software licenses, and also be sure to understand how to install programs in linux. For installing have a look at this link: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/beginners-guide-installing-software-ubuntu-apt/)

Comment: I am not have little linux experience i just install it and use it today :D

Comment: @so i must compile it as static library ?

Comment: No. Static linking is "bad" and "old", as Frank said in the previous comments. If you can, the best way is to install opencv using apt-get on linux. apt-get is a "sort of" app store (please linux users excuse me :))) ) have a look at the beginners guide for installing in linux, should be clearer after reading that)

Comment: Doing that, opencv will be installed as as a shared lib on your linux system. This is the best practice. Also, if you want to distribute (e.g. sell) your software, you can't ship it with the static library included. That involves licenses and legal stuff which I don't know very well myself, but i think that if you distribute opencv as a static lib with your project, you should also open-source your project to be ok with opencv license)